# Find prev and next element from the json array of objects using current eventid using JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, lodash, hammer

Working: To display the data in current id from Json:

```
var _getEventById = function(eventId) {

        var __findEvent = function(event) {
            return event.id === eventId;
        };

        return _.find(data.meeting.events, __findEvent);
    };
```

I want to find the prev and next events.number using the current event ID. The below code doesn't work. it is written inside the model.

```
  var _getNextEvent = function(eventNumber) {
  var nextEventNumber = data.meeting.events.number += eventNumber ;
  var nextEvent = _.find(event, function(event) {
    return event.number === nextEventNumber;
  });

  return nextEvent.id;
};


var _getPrevEvent = function(eventNumber) {
  var prevEventNumber = data.meeting.events.number -= eventNumber ;

  var prevEvent = _.find(event, function(event) {
    return event.number === prevEventNumber;
  });

  return prevEvent.id;
};
```

What I tried is to pass the current events.id and find the events.number using Lodash and add one to find the next events number. with the Next event number to return its next events.id. (subtract to find the prev event id)

```
JSON: "meeting": {
      "id": "SING_74",
      "name": "Singapore Racing",
      "runDate": "2017-10-04",
      "meetingNumber": 12,
      "closeDate": "2017-10-04",
      "open": true,
      "venue": "Overseas",
      "currentRaceId": "SING_74_2",
      "code": "RACE",
      **"events": [**
        {
          **"id": "SING_74_1",**
          **"number": 1,**
          "open": false,
          "status": "Closed"
        },
        {
          "id": "SING_74_3",
          "number": 3,
          "open": true,
          "status": "Open"
        },
        {
          "id": "SING_74_4",
          "number": 4,
          "open": true,
          "status": "Open"
        },
        {
          "id": "SING_74_5",
          "number": 5,
          "open": true,
          "status": "Open"
        },
```

Achieve: what I am trying to achieve in angular is when user swipe on the Racing/events. it should identify ng-swipe-left and ng-swipe-right and update the data with the nexteventid or preveventid.

If you share any inputs or examples are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an array of ids

```
var event_ids = data.meeting.events.map(function(e){return e.id;}):
```

Find your current id index, calculate previous and next ones:

`Math.min()` is returning the lowest value, so if you are at the end of array, and swipe one more time it will return the last index of the array `event_ids.length-1` since it will be lower than `current_id_idx+1`

`current_id_idx -1 < 0 ?  0 : current_id_idx -1` makes sure that previous index of array will never be below zero

```
var current_id_idx = events_ids.indexOf(current_id);
var prev_idx = current_id_idx -1 < 0 ?  0 : current_id_idx -1;
var next_idx = Math.min(event_ids.length-1, current_id_idx +1);
```

and finally get next or prev event number

```
 var prev_number = data.meeting.events[prev_idx].number;
 var next_number = data.meeting.events[next_idx].number;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is getEventById is the current_Id??? I cannot find the the current ID. The above code display the data on the current ID but not the ID itself.

Comment: Can I use the length as like next_idx to find the prev_idx. There are many events. User can swipe next while it reaches the last page and swipe left until they reach the first page.

Comment: `_getEventById` is the function to get event by a certain id you pass, 

so when you call that method it will return the `event` 

`var current_event  = _getEventById(current_id);`

if you call the method  `_getEventById` without passing the variable it will possibly return also an event

`var current_event  = _getEventById;`

but in this case it will try to find a global variable `eventId` and if such exists return associated event

For the second question see updated anwser